# List from guild.channels is empty

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to get A Channel from a Server. However when I try to call the guild.channels method I only get an empty List. The Guild Object is an the right Guild Object and every other Attributes from the object works just fine (e.g. guild.id, there I get the right ID from the Guld). And yes, I have enabled every Intent

Here's My Code:

```
print(guild.channels)
```

And my Output:

```
[]
```

Comment: does your bot have access to the server's channels ?

Comment: Yes, the bot even has admin permissions

Comment: Which Intents are enabled?

Comment: "And yes, I have enabled every Intent"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="prefix")
```

Try doing this

```
print(bot.get_all_channels())
```